# GTK: Define the application type vs go by simple method

Tags: c, gtk, glib, organization

In certain applications from GNOME, like `EasyTAG`, in their source code they have constructs like `G_DEFINE_TYPE`, and `et_application_get_type` (from `EasyTAG`). They use `GAction` varibles to represent actions that are run from the menubar, eg. for the `Quit` item, they would represent it in the GAction array of possible actions.
In other applications, like `LXTask`, `GManEdit`, they use signal handlers to call the function that processes the request (to quit, maybe).

Which should I use: The first or second.

I have noticed that if you use the first way, the source files are divided into files named `window`, `application_window`, `preferences_window`, eg. The second method uses the prenamed `callbacks.c`, `interface.c` always.

When browsing source code, I find the second method easier to read, because if I want to look for some functionality, i know which file to look in. The first method is not so easy because it is named after window elements, not preset filenames.

Maybe the first method is more efficient for the compiler...Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callbacks.c`/`interface.c` files used to be generated from a very old version of Glade 2.x, only for GTK 2.x, when GtkApplication didn't exist. This organization isn't really used anymore.

It's recommended to use GtkApplication; there is a [how-to](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication). You'll notice that the C example there doesn't use `G_DEFINE_TYPE` to inherit from GtkApplication, but instead uses signal handlers. The Python and JS examples do define a class that inherits from `Gtk.Application`. In C it's often more convenient to use signal handlers instead of inheritance, but you could do either one. They are mostly equivalent.